# Fragment - cancelling fragment transaction BEFORE fragment is created

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

`MyFragment` has `layout_my_fragment.xml` which has a WebView widget. `MyFragment` doesn't inflate the view itself, it uses inheritance:

`MyFragment <- ParentFragment <- GrandParentFragment (layout is inflated here)`

The goal is to check whether the phone has WebView enabled **BEFORE** inflating its layout (which would crash the app).

My solution so far:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    checkWebviewIsEnabled()

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
}

override fun checkWebviewIsEnabled(): Boolean {
    if(!isWebviewEnabled(requireActivity())) {
        findNavController().popBackStack()
    }

    return true
}
```

`findNavController().popBackStack()`, which is the normal way of exiting fragment, gets called but doesn't do anything and the `return true` is called. I suspect this is because that way only works after the fragment is created.

So how do I cancel the fragment creation before inflating its layout?

Comment: I don't believe popping backstack while fragment is being added is going to have any effect. Can't you just modify your navigation logic to check for webview availability and not add this fragment in the first place?

Comment: How are you navigating to that fragment?

Comment: @cutiko I have a `bottomNav` menu item and in `nav_graph` it's a fragment.

Comment: I can think of two approaches. The web view checking is not happening on the ui thread, and there is an exception in the logs. Try with the usual run on ui thread. If that is not the problem, then change it to `onViewCreated` not as a solution but for debugging. On a device that has web view enabled, invert the validation; if it works, then the problem is what you think. For that the solution would be making the validation before navigating to the fragment.